# Can Delphi run on a Mac with M1 processor?

Tags: windows, macos, delphi

Currently i use an Intel Mac to develop Windows x86 apps on Delphi, using Parallels virtualization.

I know these newer Apple Silicon Macs only runs Windows ARM, but has anyone tried to develop on Delphi x86 in this scenario ? Will it work reasonably ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no official way to run Windows on ARM on Apple ARM hardware.  That also means there is no official way to run x86 Windows software on Apple ARM hardware.  If I am not mistaken, Windows on ARM has the capability to run x86-x64 Windows software, but there is no official way to install it on Apple silicon hardware.  **If it works reasonably is up to the individual, in my experience, Delphi ran was performance hog (i.e. it ran horribly natively on x86 hardware).** If it ran horribly natively then I can't imagine, attempting to run through 2 layers of hardware virtualization.

Comment: [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) claims to be able to emulate x86/64 [& PPC too]. It runs on QEMU. I've not tried it myself. I've no idea if it will run Delphi.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nice, will give it a try thank you !

Comment: There is [a webinar replay on YouTube](https://youtu.be/j6o7TmOFAYA?t=1490) where Jim McKeeth demonstrates how things work on some Apple Silicone Mac with Delphi on Windows ARM on Parallels, and even with Linux x86 VM in UTM running on the same Mac at the same time, and everything goes pretty smooth...

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk Looks promising but we need to know if a real life project will compile ; a simple example is not enough. I would like to have a M1 machine here to test but i don't

Comment: I imagine and/or hope that if you name such a project, somebody with M1 or M2 might try and report results here. 

Perhaps you can find some on Github and put link here?

Comment: @delphirules , you also can use some cloud Mac to try, e.g. [Amazon's m2.metal](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#macos_workloads). Prices start at about $0.7 per hour on-demand (but not less than 24 hours).

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk That's a really great idea, will do this ! Thank you !

Comment: @delphirules , I would be very thankful if you share the results of your tests.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is still no good story for running x86 Windows software on Apple silicon.

Comment: Do you think it will be possible in the future ?